# rclone configure google workspace storage remote to list shared drive contents

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive, rclone

I am trying to setup a rclone remote with google drive storage provider
I want to list / sync files from single / multiple shared team drives inside a workspace account with a service account.

- I have created a service account,
- Enabled Drive API,
- Enabled Domain wide delegation, added the client id of the service account with drive scope
- Setup the rclone remote as a shared teams drive with service account credentials

During this last step when it asked me -

`Configure this as a Shared Drive (Team Drive)?`

I am getting the below response -

```
2022/11/10 20:08:05 DEBUG : Google Drive: config in: state="teamdrive_ok", result="true"
2022/11/10 20:08:05 DEBUG : Google Drive: config out: out=&{State:teamdrive_config Option:<nil> OAuth:<nil> Error: Result:}, err=<nil>
2022/11/10 20:08:05 DEBUG : Google Drive: config in: state="teamdrive_config", result=""
2022/11/10 20:08:05 DEBUG : Google Drive: config out: out=&{State: Option:<nil> OAuth:<nil> Error:No Shared Drives found in your account Result:}, err=<nil>
No Shared Drives found in your account
```

But now when I am trying to list the files with something like -

`rclone -v lsf --drive-impersonate username@domain.com  "remotename":`

I think I only see the user's drive contents and not the shared drive contents.
I also tried

`rclone -v lsf --drive-impersonate username@domain.com  "remotename":"shareddrivename/"`

But it says folder not found.

Can someone please help me setup the configuration here to access my shared google workspace teams drives contents via rclone?

Comment: The user you are impersonating, is he a member of the shared drive? Also if possible is the user the Super Admin of the organization?

Comment: Yes, the service account was created from the super admin account. I did try to impersonate both superadmin and other user accounts. Yes, the user I am impersonating is a manager of a shared drive

Comment: EDIT: during rclone config when I did try to setup as shared drive it wasn't able to list any shared drives. Not sure why

Comment: Try to share one of the shared drives directly with the service account to check if possible to access it that way.